# Is there a way to use item weight in a Shopping Cart Price Rule condition?

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon, price-rules, cart-rule, catalog-rules

I have a product that has two weights options, 1lbs and 2lbs. Is it possible to set a Shopping Cart Price Rule condition for only the 2lbs item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to update the `weight` attribute to set "Use for Promo Rule Conditions" = 1. This can be done via admin panel or via update script.

[image: Attribute property management screenshot]

Comment: can we use attribute "weight" for shopping cart promo rule condition? as I know it has frontend_input type weight and it is not allowed for rule condition.

Comment: @ChandreshP. out of the box, yes, at least in my latest install. Input type is text.

Comment: @benmarks. I am using magento magento CE-1.9.1.0 and Input type is weight for the weight attribute.

Comment: For "Catalog Input Type for Store Owner" there is no `weight` input type in stock Magento. It must be from a 3rd party extension.